# Flutter DropdownButton dont show value, when using hint

Tags: flutter

i have an AlertDialog and want to use a DropdownButton for changing a value. At first there should be the hint visible. After choosing a value, the value should be visible. But when i use the hint, it never shows the value and vice versa.

```
DropdownButton(
     items: <String>['team1','team2'].map((String val) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
    value: val,
    child: Text(val),
   )).toList(),
  //value: 'team1',
    hint: Text('Enter team'),
    
    onChanged: (value) {
      teteam.text = value;
    }
                ),
```

It has the correct function, but visibility isnt quite like i expect.

Answer (score 2):

I'm posting a fully working code at the bottom

For future projects in order to 'activate the hint' ability you have to meet two conditions:

Set the initial value to null and the dropdown is enabled( list of strings and onChanged are non-null. Or so the official documentation says so.

Code below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String? theTeam = null;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: DropdownButton(
          value: theTeam,
          items: <String>['team1', 'team2']
              .map((String val) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: val,
                    child: Text(val),
                  ))
              .toList(),
          hint: Text('Enter team'),
          onChanged: (String? value) {
            setState(() {
              theTeam = value!;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `setState` since you want to change the UI of your app. Simply change the `onchanged`

```
onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                teteam.text = value;
              });
            },
..
```

Working example right here:
https://www.developerlibs.com/2019/09/flutter-drop-down-menu-list-example.html

setState from library:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html

EDIT:

I assume you are trying to use `setState` in a stateless widget, which is immutable(unable to change).

Use a stateful widget to do so, like this:

```
class AddTodoDialog extends StatefulWidget{
  AddTodoDialog createState()=> AddTodoDialog();
}

class AddTodoDialog extends State<AddTodoDialog>{
 //Your code here
}
```

Comment: when i try to use SetState i cant do that actually: The method 'setState' isn't defined for the type 'AddTodoDialog'. And in that file there is no Stateful-Entry

Comment: check my answer, you need to change your class, you are using a StatelessWidget

Comment: When i do so in my file like this: ```class AddTodoDialog extends StatefulWidget{
  _AddTodoDialog createState()=> _AddTodoDialog();
}



class _AddTodoDialog extends State<AddTodoDialog>{
``` then i got a lot of other points

Comment: missing concrete implementation of State.build

Comment: you can also do it outside of your file. In your widget tree where your are using AddTodoDialog and giving an onchanged function, there you can put setstate too. Also instead of  doing negative voting on the answer, read the official library entry I provided and also check the article with the working example.

Comment: Sorry, i dont want to do negative voting :-(